# Why is an error bar rendered when placing orders on WooCommerce WordPress store?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing this problem. A red bar with only '!' is coming while pressing 'Place Order'. This thing is probably happening after updating WooCommerce database recently.

I'm attaching the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Deactivate all other plugins except WooCommerce and check it out, there may be a problem with other plugins too?

Comment: Yeah, I deactivated all the plugins except woocommerce and the problem is resolved. Now I gotta find that culprit plugin. Thanks mate! :)